# как разыменовать указатель, который является частью класса

Tags: c++

```
class test{ 
     private: 
        char* str;
```

пытаюсь перегрузить операцию сложения для двух строк и мне нужно передвинуть указатель на конец строки
обычно делается как `while(*str)` но здесь я не знаю какой синтаксис, если такой вообще есть `test1.*str или test1.(*str)` не работают

Comment: Оператор свободный (не член класса)? Извне класса обратиться к `private` нельзя, только объявляя оператор как `friend`.

Comment: вот прототип `friend test operator+(const test& s1, const test& s2);` в данной функции могу работать с `private` вопрос в том, как разыменовать указатель к которому обращаться можно через только через членство `.`

Comment: определите операторы  `++` и  `*` и выполните операции для объекта класса: `while(*test1++);`

Comment: Да что тут обращаться? `s1.str`, `*s1.str`.

Comment: действительно работает, мне такая форма записи `*s1.str` казалась неправильной поэтому не знал что делать